# Grails Application resources deployment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am running a grails application with 4 different views and it runs properly when I am running the application.

However, after I create a WAR file and deploy it in the machine there is an error on one the tabs (error regarding jQuery) (Server - Apache Tomcat 7.0.47 and grails 2.3.4)

ERROR :

> Cannot find resource file jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js

Now, this file name was not mentioned in the resources file, however this was there in the views file using g:javascript (loading)

The error on the browser console also is basically due to a jQuery conflict only

The problem is I have multiple jQuery files and they are conflicting, also prototype js is also there so we have out a jQuery no conflict to prevent that.

I want to understand how exactly is "ApplicationResource.groovy" is used and why is it used? Is it only used in production mode ?

How should js and css file be loaded? From the views page using g:javascript or from resources method?

How do I load jQuery ui and prototype both such that the error does not come.

ApplicationResources.groovy :

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'js/d3.v3.min.js'

        resource url:'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
        resource url:'js/bootstrap.min.js'
        resource url:'js/dygraph-1.0.combined.js'
        resource url:'js/spin-1.3.0.min.js'
        resource url:'js/moment-2.1.0.min.js'
        resource url:'js/JGS.ServerDataSimulator.js'
        resource url:'js/JGS.GraphDataProvider.js'
        resource url:'js/JGS.Demo1Page.js'

        resource url:'js/underscore.js'
        resource url:'js/crossfilter.js'
        resource url:'js/dc.js'
        resource url:'js/prototype.js'
        resource url:'js/highcharts.js'
        resource url:'js/exporting.js'


    }
}
```

And it was missing file - 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js' which is mentioned and loaded in view files using :

```
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"/>
```

However, this is throwing up jquery not defined or conflict errors.

I really need to understand the correct way of loading files. Is it using ApplicationResources or using g:javascript in views?

JS File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <title>EWACS Site performance tool</title>
        <g:javascript src="d3.v3.min.js"/>
        <g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"/>
        <g:javascript src="jQDateRangeSlider-min.js"/>
        <g:javascript src="jQDateRangeSlider-withRuler-min.js"/>
        <g:javascript src="jQRangeSliderLabel.js"/> 

    <script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict()
    </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'iThing.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'dc.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main_div.css')}" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>

    <g:javascript src="prototype.js"/>
    <g:javascript src="highcharts.js"/>
    <g:javascript src="exporting.js"/>
</head>
```

All approches/suggestions are most welcome

Comment: Please provide further information. Share your `ApplicationResource.groovy` and one of your views with the `<g:javascript/>` tag

Comment: Where is your js-file located in the file system?

Comment: Js files are in /web-app/js, will update the question now.

Comment: jquery and prototype together?

Comment: Hence the problem, but in js files, I have mentioned the noconflict and used $j throughout. What is the purpose of ApplicationResources.groovy? Can't just defining js and css files in views enough?

Comment: the purpose of course obsolete now due to move over to assets is to allow you to define groups of resources so application resources custom1 resources each having each own js/css and relationships - which can be called custom per page or overall in the layouts..https://github.com/PureSrc/grails-arrested-plugin/blob/master/src/templates/configuration/ApplicationResources.groovy have a look here - you can see different definitions and hierachy of dependencies

Comment: So, should i completely empty my file, or should i load all files in the Application file? I tried loading all files, I'm getting errors of noconflict again etc

Comment: you have piled everything into one call - you could call in one at a time and see what your conflict is.. I suspect its the other jquery call resource url:'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'  ...

Comment: I was able to fix it, I commented the entire ApplicationResources.groovy and I'm calling files only via view files in grails!

Comment: that means on each gsp you need to define the same thing - at least do it in your layouts/main.gsp - that way every page can use the same files without you having to manually define it each/every time you require it.